# printf() in PostgreSQL's bufmgr.c?

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying few modifications.

In `postgres/src/backend/storage/buffer/bufmgr.c` I want to make few print outs, so I tried `printf` and some multiple `fprintf` but none of these things seem to work.

Some of the search results says me to use `RAISE NOTICE` but i don't think it's the right way to do it.

So is there any elegant way to do `printf` in that folder?

Comment: I think could be a good idea to post the code you wrote so far..

Comment: It's really simple. In BufferSync() Fuction. I just made print out "num_to_write" that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how PostgreSQL is configured and how it's managed/launched by init scripts etc, stdout and stderr might go to the main PostgreSQL logs, a special log only used for PostgreSQL startup, or even to `/dev/null`. (Specifically, take a look at the logging collector settings, the `-l` option to `pg_ctl`, and your init scripts).

Rather than rely on stdout or stderr, I suggest [using the `elog` and `ereport` macros](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/error-message-reporting.html) to use PostgreSQL's logging system. This will send information to the same place as the rest of the logs, where you'll see and find it. They take `printf`-like format strings.

e.g.

```
elog(DEBUG1, "The value of x is %u", someuint32var);
```

`elog` is for short messages that don't need much explanation or context, mostly debug messages.

The `ereport` macro is intended for more detailed user-facing messages. See existing examples in the code, and the PostgreSQL documentation chapter on error message conventions.

That said, it's often useful to just `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` and attach `gdb` to the running process, set some breakpoints/watchpoints, and explore what you want interactively. That way you don't have to constantly recompile and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you!  It really helped me a lot. :)